# How to assign value to autogenrated ID in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
public class Categorie {

    private Long id;
    private String nom;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

What I need is:

1) id == null (id is not assigned), the strategy is auto increment

2) id != null (id is assigned), persist the entity with assigned value

Help please

Comment: seems You want break JPA idea. Why? Give real-life example

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The call to merge() or persist() will either update or insert if id is present or not.

Comment: You have an odd idea of autogenerated IDs.  ID autogeneration is not a fallback strategy; where applied, it is *the* strategy.  You do not get to choose IDs for any entities of types whose IDs are autogenerated.

Comment: why would you want to do such thing?

Comment: JPA does not allow for that situation; it either assigns the value (when you specify `@GeneratedValue`) or not (when not specified). I know that DataNucleus JPA provides the option of doing exactly as you want (only generate when null), but that is a vendor extension

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to remove auto generated annotation. get a auto generated id by calling nextval of the sequence manually from the database writing native query and then assign it to entity

remove sequence generator from entity class

```
@Id
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

check if id exists else fetch it from database

```
if(catagorieObject.getId()==null){
catogorieObject.setId(getidFromSeq()); 
}
```

get the sequence id by calling

```
public Long getidFromSeq(){
 .......
String query="select SOME_SEQUENCE.nextVal from dual";
 .....
}
```

Comment: I found this exception  "nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'SOME_SEQUENCE'"

Comment: Man ! 'SOME_SEQUENCE' is the dummy sequence name i provided as you didn't provide name of the sequence generator in your @GeneratedValue(). replace SOME_SEQUENCE with your sequence created for your Categorie  entity

Answer (score 0):

merge the entity instance via EntityManager#merge() rather than persist the entity instance using EntityManager#persist()